# How to compare two instances of the same condition in sql?

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE researcher 
(
    rid PRIMARY KEY,
    name,
    institution,
    city,
    country
)

CREATE TABLE paper 
(
    title PRIMARY KEY,
    journal,
    volume,
    number,
    year
)

CREATE TABLE author 
(
    resid FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES researcher.rid,
    title FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES paper.title
)
```

I need to list the journals that published more papers in 2019 than in 2018 in queries in SQL.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT
    journal
FROM
    paper
GROUP BY
    journal
HAVING
    COUNT(title)
WHERE
    year = 2019 > year = 2018
```

Since I can't have `condition > condition`, how I can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional expressions . . .

```
SELECT journal
FROM PAPER
GROUP BY journal
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2019 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2018 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in SQL, the logical order of a `SELECT` statement is (*in general*) actually:

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. SELECT
6. ORDER BY

With that in mind...

### Step 1: Get a listing of Journals and the number of papers they had in each specific year:

```
SELECT
    journal,
    [year]
    COUNT( CASE WHEN [year] = 2018 THEN 1 END ) AS PaperCountIn2018,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN [year] = 2019 THEN 1 END ) AS PaperCountIn2019
FROM
    paper
GROUP BY
    journal,
    [year]
```

### Step 2: Filter it in an outer-query:

(@GordonLinoff's answer does it in a single query by moving the predicate to the `HAVING` clause, whereas I prefer using outer-queries).

```
SELECT
    journalPaperCounts.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            journal,
            [year]
            COUNT( CASE WHEN [year] = 2018 THEN 1 END ) AS PaperCountIn2018,
            COUNT( CASE WHEN [year] = 2019 THEN 1 END ) AS PaperCountIn2019
        FROM
            paper
        GROUP BY
            journal,
            [year]
    ) AS journalPaperCounts
WHERE
    journalPaperCounts.PaperCountIn2018 > PaperCountIn2019
```